# Error in rgeos::createPolygonsComment(oobj) : orphaned hole using geojsonio in R

Tags: r, geojson, rgdal, r-maptools, geojsonio

Im am trying to create a `.geojson` file in my local repository for [this output](https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v2/malhas/21?formato=application/vnd.geo+json). I am downloading the file locally, making my adjustments and writing `input21.geojson`, however, I get the message:

```
Error in rgeos::createPolygonsComment(oobj) : 
rgeos_PolyCreateComment: orphaned hole, cannot find containing polygon for hole at index 51
```

My code so far:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rgdal)
library(downloader)
library(geojsonio)
library(maptools)


u <- paste0('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v2/malhas/21?formato=application/vnd.geo+json')

downloader::download(url = u, destfile = "/tmp/gas.GeoJSON")
gas <- readOGR(dsn = "/tmp/gas.GeoJSON")

gas$var0031 <- 21
gas$var0517 <- 0 
gas$var0514  <- as.numeric(substr(as.character(gas$var0031),1,1))
gas$var0512 <- "MA"
gas$var0513 <- "Maranhão"
gas <- gas[which(names(gas) %in% c("var0517", "var0031", "var0514", "var0512", "var0513"))]

geojsonio::geojson_write(gas, file = paste0("./data/in/sidra_malhas/input21.geojson"))
```

Comment: `geojsonio` maintainer here. the error is happening here https://github.com/ropensci/geojsonio/blob/master/R/zzz.r#L318 with `maptools::checkPolygonsHoles` - not sure why that's erroring, but the docs for that fxn should help sort out whats going on

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance, but what would fxn be? I have tried `slot(gas, "polygons") <- lapply(slot(gas, "polygons"), checkPolygonsHoles)` as well like [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113964/fixing-orphaned-holes-in-r), but still the same problem.

Comment: sorry, fxn shorthand for function

Answer (score 0):

I Have figured a package called `cleangeo` that corrects some issues related with geo structure, adding the lines solve the problem:

```
gas <- cleangeo::clgeo_Clean(gas)
slot(gas, "polygons") <- lapply(slot(gas, "polygons"), checkPolygonsHoles)
```

before the line:

```
geojsonio::geojson_write(gas, file = paste0("./data/in/sidra_malhas/input21.geojson"))
```